# Javascript oop instance of object

Tags: javascript, oop

If I do

```
var a={a:1}
```

So a is instance of Object with more property?
How does it work?

Comment: What you have there is an object literal being assigned to `a`.  Does that answer your question?  If not, can you be more specific?

Comment: You want to make a `class` or something?

Comment: My question is if the variable a is instance of some class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What will happen in that statement is that a variable named `a` will be created.

The `a` inside the `{a:1}` is a property name, not a reference to the variable `a`.

Hence, `a.a` will give you `1`.

Comment: Is the variable a is instance of some class?

Comment: In this case `a` is an instance of `Object` which everything inherits from in javascript. `{}` is an object literal and is the same as saying `a = new Object; a.a = 1;`.